# Are names of computer game characters copyrighted?

Tags: copyright, software

I am **not** developing a game or creating game characters. What I am trying to do is give a name to the software that I am creating in my spare time. It seems there is a game character by the same name, a popular game at that (I am not a gamer but a google search to check the name revealed it). The software is intended to be free but might make money in the future, so I want to know this.

**Are names of characters in games copyrighted and is it illegal to use them to name other unrelated software components and applications that might or might not make money?**

Comment: I would think this *depends upon the name*. i.e.  "Cole" (Infamous/Sony) clearly can't be in itself. It's very general and broad.  Where as "Nathan Drake" (Uncharted/Sony) may be because it is far more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A name cannot be copyrighted](http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ34.pdf), as names, titles, and short phrases are too small to constitute a copyrightable work.

A name *can* be protected under trademark. Trademark law is designed to protect consumers, by helping them reliably identify the source of a good or service. If your use of a name is likely to confuse consumers about the source of your product because (1) the name is similar to a trademarked name, and (2) the nature of your product is one that consumers might reasonably believe could be offered by the owner of the original trademark, then you might lose a trademark suit for your use of the name.

The domains are somewhat similar in your case (video games and whatever software you're writing), so there's *maybe* some possibility for confusion, but ultimately, whether there is valid case for confusion is a determination up to the courts.

See also [Naming free software and avoiding trademark collision](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/9120/84).

Comment: Ah! Trademark. Thanks. (I'll check but I think game characters aren't trademarked...may be I could beat them to it. The name is borrowed from my culture anyway so I might have more 'claim' to it if it comes down to that. Just thinking aloud here.)